# Unsupported Media Type error for asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I send a POST request then I get this error:

```json
{
  "type" : "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
  "title" : "Unsupported Media Type",
  "status" : 415,
  "traceId" : "|3866e04e-4b62c808bec91a8c."
}
```

The model class

```cs
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApi.Models;
    
namespace WebApi
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(User user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.Username);
            Console.WriteLine(user.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

And .cshtml file:

```html
<form method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" asp-for="Username"/><br>
    Password: <input type="password" asp-for="Password"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND POST REQUEST">
</form>
```

Comment: Make sure the content type accepted matches the content type you are sending in your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your controller is apicontroller,it would get json data by default,but you send a form data,so you need to specify the source by adding `[FromForm]` attribute to your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromForm]User user)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.Username);
    Console.WriteLine(user.Password);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Really thanks you! I thought, an ApiController is required to correct operation of the controller. So far, I have only read from Polish sources, which are very few. This functionality I have read on some forum. Thanks you again, thanks! :D